# Sensors for Raspberry PI accessable from Java

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

i want to use some sensors for the RPi which i can access with java.
can i use any sensors that I connect to the GPIO?
e.g.: sunfounder starter kit?

[http://www.amazon.com/Sunfounder-Raspberry-Extension-H-Bridge-7-Segment/dp/B00P2E9W30/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1434575352&sr=8-2&keywords=raspberry+pi+sunfounder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00P2E9W30)

thank you for your answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pi4J](http://pi4j.com/) to use "devices" connected to the GPIO